# Debug Draw Andengine

Tags: debugging, opengl-es-2.0, draw, andengine

Is there a Debugdraw (physic bodys + joints), for current Andengine GELS2?
The only available is for GELS1: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/12/10/understanding-box2d-debug-draw/

Comment: It is GLES, not GELS. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to ask in the official forum andengine.org too.
Good luck.